# SQL wildcard matching on single character

Tags: php, sql-server

I am working on AJAX search which searches a SQL database. I have the following SQL code:

```
$query = odbc_exec(
    $connection,
    "SELECT * 
       FROM view_all_information
      WHERE (cn LIKE '%{$query}%')
         OR (mail LIKE '%{$query}%')
         OR (company  LIKE '%{$query}%')
         OR (title  LIKE '%{$query}%')
         OR department LIKE ('%{$query}%')
         OR (functions LIKE '%{$query}%')
         OR (languages LIKE '%{$query}%')
    "
);
```

The problem is that, when I type in the word sql, it seems to bring back any instance of s, q and l. I can't figure this out and nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: to bring back every instance of whatever is typed in, e.g. sql

Comment: I find this query fine as per your expected result e.g. typing "amer" will produce: '%amer%' and will result 'american', 'america', 'gramer'. Let me know if there is any combination that you're looking for.